# Strange character when using listings package

Tags: listings

I'm seeing an odd character like a very flat U, where there should be a space, with the `listings package`. See example below. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening, or how to get rid or work around it?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{underscore}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames, rgb, svgnames, x11names]{xcolor}
% Text layout
\topmargin 0.0cm
\oddsidemargin 0.5cm
\evensidemargin 0.5cm
\textwidth 16cm
\textheight 21cm 
\lstnewenvironment{cmd}[1][]{%
  \lstset{language=sh, backgroundcolor=\color{LightSteelBlue1}, #1}}
{}

\begin{document}
\begin{cmd}[caption=Configuration file section including filters]
[affy6]
[...]
    [[hapmap]]
    phenofiles = "data/Hapmap6.0/Pheno/hapmappheno_909.csv",
    genofile = "/data/snppy/Hapmap6.0/Geno/birdseed-v2.calls.txt"
    anno_filter = "chromosome = 5"
    idlink_filter = "studyid = 'CEU'"
    some_other_stuff = "foo = bar"
\end{cmd}
\end{document}
```

[image: picture of the output]

Comment: Please try to load \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} and maybe the font berano or so

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: Why?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

By default, [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) shows spaces as a "squat-u" as part of strings (between quotes). Add the option `showstringspaces=false` to your list of `\lstset` options to remove this.

[image]

Comment: Wow, thanks Werner. I just assumed this was a bug, and didn't look at the manual, which states this behavior clearly. But why on earth would anyone want this as a default?

Comment: @FaheemMitha: In terms of programming, code sometimes have whitespace for readability. However, in terms of strings (typically used to produce output or assigned to variables), it may be very important if you use one or two spaces, say. TeX is similar in the sense that it gobbles spaces in code as needed, but not with string comparisons. For example: `\def\strA{this that}\def\strB{this  ` `that}\ifx\strA\strB true\else false\fi` will yield `false`, while `\strA` and `\strB` will typeset *exactly* the same in the output.

Comment: I'm amazed this isn't turned off by default, thank you!

Comment: If you need to get rid of the "underscores" in listings follow this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/77745/81156