# Weird symbol in white spaces inside listings environment

Tags: listings

I get that symbol inside quotes in listings environment. It seems to appear only inside quotes.Outside of them it seems that is not happenning the same thing. Why do I have that problem and how can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Please provide a minimum working example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `listings` package shows spaces within strings by default. You can turn it off by calling `\lstset{showstringspaces=false}` somewhere in the preamble. (If you already use `lstset` to set other things, then you can just add this attribute to that call.)

See also: [Strange character when using listings package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54183/strange-character-when-using-listings-package)
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Source_Code_Listings#Settings

Comment: Thank you very much! I added it as I have a fairly rich `lstset` preamble!