# Special characters in a lstlisting

Tags: input-encodings

I'm trying to paste my SQL code but my spaces are being interpreted as special chars and I get a weird character between words.

Here's my code:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[
           language=SQL,
           showspaces=false,
           basicstyle=\ttfamily,
           numbers=left,
           numberstyle=\tiny,
           commentstyle=\color{gray},
           breaklines=true
        ]

.bail ON
.mode columns
.headers on
.nullvalue NULL
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
.width 25 25 25 25 25 25 25

--FICHEIRO PARA INTRODUCAO DOS DADOS NAS TABELAS JA CRIADAS

--Tabela TipoAcidente
INSERT INTO TipoAcidente(tipoAcidenteID, nome, descricaoAcidente) VALUES (1, 'Choque traseiro', 'Carro A travou de repente e o carro B não conseguiu evitar choque');
INSERT INTO TipoAcidente(tipoAcidenteID, nome, descricaoAcidente) VALUES (2, 'Choque Lateral', 'Carro A embateu de lado no carro B, após o carro B ter ignorado um stop');
INSERT INTO TipoAcidente(tipoAcidenteID, nome, descricaoAcidente) VALUES (3, 'Choque Lateral', 'Carro A nao respeito o semaforo e chocou com carro B');
INSERT INTO TipoAcidente(tipoAcidenteID, nome, descricaoAcidente) VALUES (4, 'Choque Frontal', 'Carro A perdeu o controlo do carro devido a aquaplanagem e embateu no carro B');
INSERT INTO TipoAcidente(tipoAcidenteID, nome, descricaoAcidente) VALUES (5, 'Avaria do Motor', 'O motor do carro A deixou de funcionar,devido ao aquecimento');
INSERT INTO TipoAcidente(tipoAcidenteID, nome, descricaoAcidente) VALUES (6, 'Furo do Pneu', 'Condutor do carro A embateu na berma do passeio quando realizava manobras de estacionamento');

\end{lstlisting}
```

And here's the output:

[image]

Any idea how to solve this?

Best regards

Comment: Please provide a compilable document, not just fragments. And please look into your other questions -- there are answers to them, but you have not accepted a single on -- this is not how TeX.SX works!

Comment: related: [Strange character when using listings package](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/54183/579)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`listings` treats spaces in normal listing text and in strings differently. If the characters should vanish everywhere, use `showstringspaces=false` in addition to `showspaces=false`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}


\begin{lstlisting}[
           language=SQL,
           showspaces=false,
           showstringspaces=false,
           basicstyle=\ttfamily,
           numbers=left,
           numberstyle=\tiny,
           commentstyle=\color{gray},
           breaklines=true
        ]

.bail ON
.mode columns
.headers on
.nullvalue NULL
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
.width 25 25 25 25 25 25 25

--FICHEIRO PARA INTRODUCAO DOS DADOS NAS TABELAS JA CRIADAS

--Tabela TipoAcidente
INSERT INTO TipoAcidente(tipoAcidenteID, nome, descricaoAcidente) VALUES (1, 'Choque traseiro', 'Carro A travou de repente e o carro B não conseguiu evitar choque');
INSERT INTO TipoAcidente(tipoAcidenteID, nome, descricaoAcidente) VALUES (2, 'Choque Lateral', 'Carro A embateu de lado no carro B, após o carro B ter ignorado um stop');
INSERT INTO TipoAcidente(tipoAcidenteID, nome, descricaoAcidente) VALUES (3, 'Choque Lateral', 'Carro A nao respeito o semaforo e chocou com carro B');
INSERT INTO TipoAcidente(tipoAcidenteID, nome, descricaoAcidente) VALUES (4, 'Choque Frontal', 'Carro A perdeu o controlo do carro devido a aquaplanagem e embateu no carro B');
INSERT INTO TipoAcidente(tipoAcidenteID, nome, descricaoAcidente) VALUES (5, 'Avaria do Motor', 'O motor do carro A deixou de funcionar,devido ao aquecimento');
INSERT INTO TipoAcidente(tipoAcidenteID, nome, descricaoAcidente) VALUES (6, 'Furo do Pneu', 'Condutor do carro A embateu na berma do passeio quando realizava manobras de estacionamento');

\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]