# Remove ugly space under lstlisting

Tags: lstlisting

the following code :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}


\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{ 
    backgroundcolor=\color{gray!10},   % choose the background color; you must add \usepackage{color} or \usepackage{xcolor}; should come as last argument
    %basicstyle=\footnotesize,        % the size of the fonts that are used for the code
    breakatwhitespace=false,         % sets if automatic breaks should only happen at whitespace
    breaklines=true,                 % sets automatic line breaking
    captionpos=b,                    % sets the caption-position to bottom
    commentstyle=\color{cyan},    % comment style
    escapeinside={\%*}{*)},          % if you want to add LaTeX within your code
    extendedchars=true,              % lets you use non-ASCII characters; for 8-bits encodings only, does not work with UTF-8
    keepspaces=true,                 % keeps spaces in text, useful for keeping indentation of code (possibly needs columns=flexible)
    keywordstyle=\color{darkblue},       % keyword style
    language=bash,       
    % numbers=left,             % the language of the code
    otherkeywords={xxx},
    numbersep=5pt,                   % how far the line-numbers are from the code
    showspaces=false,                % show spaces everywhere adding particular underscores; it overrides 'showstringspaces'
    showstringspaces=false,          % underline spaces within strings only
    showtabs=false,                  % show tabs within strings adding particular underscores
    stepnumber=1,                    % the step between two line-numbers. If it's 1, each line will be numbered
    stringstyle=\color{red},     % string literal style
    tabsize=2,                     % sets default tabsize to 2 spaces
    title=\lstname                   % show the filename of files included with \lstinputlisting; also try caption instead of title
}
\begin{document}
\sffamily


  \begin{lstlisting}[language=bash,caption={xxx}]
    ubuntu@kubernetesmaster:~$ sudo apt get install
        \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Gives me :
 [image: Output]

How can I remove the ugly gray under the command?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Adding `belowskip=0pt` to your `\lstset` removes all space after the listing.

Comment: The culprit are the spaces before `\end{lstlisting}` which add another line...

Comment: Off topic here, but people landing here may be actually looking for [Strange character when using listings package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/54183/61949).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, simply remove some blanks causing your second line in listing:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=bash,caption={xxx}]
  ubuntu@kubernetesmaster:~$ sudo apt get install
\end{lstlisting}
```

With the complete corrected mwe

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}


\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{ 
    backgroundcolor=\color{gray!10},   % choose the background color; you must add \usepackage{color} or \usepackage{xcolor}; should come as last argument
    %basicstyle=\footnotesize,        % the size of the fonts that are used for the code
    breakatwhitespace=false,         % sets if automatic breaks should only happen at whitespace
    breaklines=true,                 % sets automatic line breaking
    captionpos=b,                    % sets the caption-position to bottom
    commentstyle=\color{cyan},    % comment style
    escapeinside={\%*}{*)},          % if you want to add LaTeX within your code
    extendedchars=true,              % lets you use non-ASCII characters; for 8-bits encodings only, does not work with UTF-8
    keepspaces=true,                 % keeps spaces in text, useful for keeping indentation of code (possibly needs columns=flexible)
    keywordstyle=\color{darkblue},       % keyword style
    language=bash,       
    % numbers=left,             % the language of the code
    otherkeywords={xxx},
    numbersep=5pt,                   % how far the line-numbers are from the code
    showspaces=false,                % show spaces everywhere adding particular underscores; it overrides 'showstringspaces'
    showstringspaces=false,          % underline spaces within strings only
    showtabs=false,                  % show tabs within strings adding particular underscores
    stepnumber=1,                    % the step between two line-numbers. If it's 1, each line will be numbered
    stringstyle=\color{red},     % string literal style
    tabsize=2,                     % sets default tabsize to 2 spaces
    title=\lstname                   % show the filename of files included with \lstinputlisting; also try caption instead of title
}


\begin{document}
\sffamily

\begin{lstlisting}[language=bash,caption={xxx}]
  ubuntu@kubernetesmaster:~$ sudo apt get install
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

you get the result:

[image: result]